# Why are embedded newlines in command expansion replaced with whitespaces?

Tags: bash

From Bash manual about the result of command expansion

> Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.

For example

```
$ cat myfile
1
2
3

$ echo $(cat myfile)
1 2 3
```

I wonder why  embedded newlines are replaced with whitespaces? The manual doesn't say so, does it?

Comment: **`removed during word splitting`**

Comment: In the output `echo $(cat myfile)`, does the bash manual say why the words are separated by white spaces, instead of not being seperated?

Comment: If you want to preserve the newlines, wrap the `$(...)` in double-quotes.  The entire output of the command-substitution will be treated as a single string.  e.g. `echo "$(cat myfile)"`

Comment: That's the _split+glob_ operator.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (1) What is "glob"? I think it is something like a regex for filename matching. (2) what do you refer to as the split+glob operator?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=split%2Bglob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash (and many other shells), `$()` is used to take the output of a command, and use it as the arguments of another command.

Here, what it does is :

First execute `cat` :

```
1
2
3
```

Then substitute the `$()` block with this :

```
echo 1
2
3
```

Now the shell needs to interpret this input, and send correct arguments to `echo`. To do that it must split `1`, `2` and `3` in words : This is where the newlines are removed.

Finally, the shell sends the following :

Program : `echo`

Arguments : `1` `2` `3`

This will display what you saw :

```
1 2 3
```

Because when `echo` has several arguments, it displays all of them separated with space.

Answer (score 2):

bew78 has answered the question, but just to make it more explicit --

Starting with [command substitution](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n4663) in the source code, it calls [word_list_split()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n9108), which itself then calls [word_split()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n9085), which *then* calls [list_string()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n2400), which [specifically](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n2528) skips over IFS separators. That creates separate "words" that the list_string() function then returns up the stack. That's how 1, 2, and 3 end up as separate parameters to the `echo` command.