# Getting different results running same commands step by step at a terminal and within a script

Tags: shell-script, head, pgrep

```
pid=$(pgrep 'engrampa') #Get the PID of the engrampa processes .
killpid=$(echo $pid | head -1) #Get only the first line of the $pid variable and put into a new variable called $killpid.
kill $killpid
```

I want to maintain only the first line of the variable `$pid`.

Let's say I have 3 instances of the `engrampa` process open.

When I run the commands above step by step at terminal, I get exactly what I want: `2590`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3U2g.jpg

When I run those exaclty commands in a script I get this result: `2590 18425 18449`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuGX9.jpg

Why is that happening?

Comment: Which shell are you using in the terminal? perhaps it is not word-splitting the unquoted `$pid`, whereas the non-interactive `bash` shell is (see for example [Why are embedded newlines in command expansion replaced with whitespaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267931/why-are-embedded-newlines-in-command-expansion-replaced-with-whitespaces))

Comment: There is an excellent article on how to do [process management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) at Greg's Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Identified my problem thanks to steeldriver comment.

Running `echo $pid | head -1` in `bash` do nothing. Running the same command at `zsh` shell I get exactly what I want.

bash shell output -> `2590 18425 18449`

zsh shell output -> `2590`

That being stated, my problem has been solved changing the shell of the script to `#!/bin/zsh`.

**Edit: Another solution, and more suitable, is just using `echo $pid | awk '{print $1}'` instead `echo $pid | head -1`. It works on both shell. Thanks to Christopher comment.**

Comment: Your original version would have worked in `bash` if you'd quoted the variable: `echo "$pid" | head -1`. However you might want to consider using `pgrep -n` or `pgrep -o`  (or `pidof` with the `-s` switch) so as to avoid piping to `head` altogether.